# code generation from an architecture

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

Hello I am generating a Kinetic JavaScript code from the Sparx "enterprise architect" tool from VB Script. The problem I am facing is
1) I am able to generate the code from the model here I have no problem.But I would like to generate the output in a sequence from left side of the model to the bottom right.
Now how my output is generated is when I add a new component that component output is generated first and followed by other.[image]

Here is my model here I am generating the output as:
1) Birt
2) igpk .....
But I want in sequence like 
1) GS-IS
2) Promics
3)FMEA
4) iGPK... [image]

```
option explicit

!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript


'
sub main
    if (Repository.GetTreeSelectedItemType() = otDiagram) then

        ' Show the script output window
        Repository.EnsureOutputVisible "Script"

        dim theDiagram as EA.Diagram
        set theDiagram = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject()

        dim doOffsetLeft, doOffsetRight, doOffsetTop, doOffsetBottom 'As Integer
        dim scaleX, scaleY 'As Integer

        dim inputpicSizeX, inputpicSizeY, newpicSizeX1, newpicSizeY2 'As Integer

        dim decreasex, newdecreasex, decreasey, newdecreasey  ' as Integer
        dim connectLink 'As String

         scalex = theDiagram.cx 
         scaley = theDiagram.cy
        connectLink=""
        'doOffsetLeft = 35
        'doOffsetTop = 9





        Session.Output("scaleX: " + CStr(scaleX) + "scaleY: " + CStr(scaleY)) 'this have the whole pick size'

        connectLink=InputBox("Connect URL for tool list?", "Input required", connectLink)

        ' next have to take input box and have to calculate % '


        newpicSizeX1 = CInt(InputBox("Exported image width (in pixels)?", "Input required", inputpicSizeX))
        newpicSizeY2 = CInt(InputBox("Exported image height (in pixels)?", "Input required", inputpicSizeY))

        Session.Output("NewscaleX: " + CStr(newpicSizeX1) + "NewscaleY: " + CStr(newpicSizeY2)) 'new scale stored here given by user'

        'calculation of % x'

        decreasex = scalex - newpicSizex1
        newdecreasex = ( decreasex / scalex ) * 100


        'calculation of % y'

        decreasey = scaley - newpicSizeY2
        newdecreasey = ( decreasey/ scaley ) * 100


        Session.Output("%decreasex:  " + CStr(newdecreasex) + " %decreasey: " + CStr(newdecreasey) )'new % output'





        dim diagramObjects as EA.Collection     
        Set diagramObjects = theDiagram.DiagramObjects

        dim diagramObject As EA.DiagramObject

        dim x1
    dim y1
    dim x2
    dim y2

    dim width
        dim height

        dim seqCnt
        dim found
        dim findIdx


        seqCnt = 0

        found = true
        while (found) 
            seqCnt = seqCnt + 1

            findIdx = 0
            found = false           
            while ((Not found) and (findIdx < diagramObjects.Count))                

                Set diagramObject = diagramObjects.GetAt(findIdx)


                if (diagramObject.Sequence = seqCnt) Then                   

                    dim doLeft, doRight, doTop, doBottom 'As Integer
                    dim element AS EA.Element



                    set element = Repository.GetElementByID(diagramObject.ElementID)




                                x1 =  CInt(diagramObject.left * (( 100 - newdecreasex )/100) ) - 28


                                y1 = CInt(-1 * diagramObject.top  * (( 100 - newdecreasey )/100)) - 42



                                x2 = 1 * CInt(diagramObject.right * (( 100 - newdecreasex )/100) ) - 28


                                y2 = CInt(-1 * diagramObject.bottom * (( 100 - newdecreasey )/100)) -45

                                width = x2 - x1
                                height = -1 * (y1 - y2)

                    if (element.Type = "ActivityPartition") Then

                            dim ElementName
                            ElementName =  Replace(element.Name, " ", "")

                        'for drawing rectangle  outer boundry

                            Session.Output("var " & ElementName & " = new Kinetic.Rect({")
                        'Session.Output("X:" & X1 & "," "Y:" & y1 & "," "Width:" & width &  "," "Height:" & height & "," "Stroke Width:2})")
                            Session.Output("x : " & X1 & ",")
                            Session.Output("y : " & y1 & ",")
                            Session.Output("width : " & width & ",")
                            Session.Output("height : " & height & ",")

                            Session.Output("strokeWidth : 2 " & "," )
                            Session.Output("stroke : 'Black'" & "," & "});")
                        'layer.add(EngineeringData);
                            Session.Output("layer.add(" & ElementName & ");")


                        'for drawing outer boundry line


                            dim ElementLine
                            dim linewidth
                            dim ywidth
                            'ElementLine = join(ElementName,"line")
                            ElementLine = ( Elementname & "line" )
                            'Session.Output (ElementLine)
                            ywidth = (y1+20)  'line should come down so adding 20
                            linewidth= (width+X1)  ' till where the line has to end so width + x1 value

                        'for drawing line
                            Session.Output("var " & ElementLine & " = new Kinetic.Line({")
                        'Session.Output("X:" & X1 & "," "Y:" & y1 & "," "Width:" & width &  "," "Height:" & height & "," "Stroke Width:2})")
                            Session.Output("points : " & "[" & X1 & "," & ywidth & "," & linewidth & "," & ywidth & "]," )
                            Session.Output("stroke : 'black' " & "," )
                            Session.Output("strokeWidth : 2 " & "," )
                            Session.Output("tension : 0 " & "," )
                            Session.Output("linecap : 'round'" & "," & "});")
                            Session.Output("layer.add(" & ElementLine & ");")

                        'for drawing message text 

                            dim Elementtext 
                            Elementtext = (Elementname & "text")
                            dim ActivityName 
                            ActivityName = element.Name

                            'Session.Output( Elementtext)
                            Session.Output("var " & Elementtext & " = new Kinetic.Text({")
                        'Session.Output("X:" & X1 & "," "Y:" & y1 & "," "Width:" & width &  "," "Height:" & height & "," "Stroke Width:2})")
                            Session.Output("x : " & X1 & ",")
                            Session.Output("y : " & y1 & ",")
                            Session.Output("width : " & width & ",")
                            Session.Output("height : " & height & ",")

                            Session.Output("text :  " &  "'" & ActivityName & "'" & "," )
                            Session.Output("fontSize : 17 "  & "," )
                            Session.Output("fontFamily : 'Calibri' "  & "," )
                            Session.Output("fill : 'black' "  & "," )
                            Session.Output("align : 'center'" & "," & "});")
                        'layer.add(EngineeringData);
                            Session.Output("layer.add(" & Elementtext & ");")



                    end if                  

'                   diagramObjects.DeleteAt findIdx,true                    
                    found = true
                end if

                findIdx = findIdx + 1
            wend            
        wend



    else
        ' Error message
        Session.Prompt "This script does not support items of this type.", promptOK     
    end if

end sub

function TVGetElementTaggedValue( theElement, taggedValueName, defaultValueMissing, defaultValueEmpty )

    if not theElement is nothing and Len(taggedValueName) > 0 then      
        dim taggedValue as EA.TaggedValue
        set taggedValue = theElement.TaggedValues.GetByName( taggedValueName )

        if taggedValue is nothing then
            TVGetElementTaggedValue = defaultValueMissing
' Dump warning          
'Session.Output(theElement.Name & " " & taggedValueName & " TAG Missing")           
        else
            if taggedValue.Value = "" then
                TVGetElementTaggedValue = defaultValueEmpty     
' Dump warning          
'Session.Output(theElement.Name & " " & taggedValueName & " Value Missing")         
            else
                TVGetElementTaggedValue = taggedValue.Value
            end if
        end if
    end if

end function


main
```

Comment: I can't understand why the order is important. I code is generated then it's a batch and in the end you have your code - or you don't.

Comment: The order is very very important for me because I am generating a  Kinetic Javascript code from VB script. Right now I am getting the output there is no problem at all but I want from left to the bottom right of the diagram.

Comment: If you generate the code from VB (and not using that awkward scripting language from Sparx) you can use the order of the elements in the project tree. IIRC it's the Pos property. Note that the order underlies very crude orders. I explained that on Sparx forum once. Best you force the order be manually moving one element up/down.

Comment: check the above code I have added a VB script code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows that you loop over the elements in the diagram. They are not ordered geographically but in order of addition. You might check the coordinate in DiagramObject to find the positional order. If you have a left to right order just check DiagramObject.Left (left y-coordinate) and sort the objects ascending.

Comment: I think this will produce me a output as GS-IS, Igpk,Request one....then promics? but not GS-IS, Promics,FMEA,Igpk...

Comment: Depends on how you evaluate the coordinates. Anyhow, I'd rather stick to the order in the project browser. This is more easy to evaluate. If you create nested elements you can arrange them as in your picture and you're save that the order is ok.

Answer (score 0):

EA ignores diagrams when generating code. (Otherwise, what would happen if you placed the same elements in a different order in another diagram?)

You might be able to affect the generation order by reordering the elements in the project browser, but I doubt that too.

If you want to enforce a particular generation order, I think you'll end up having to write your own code generation scripts.

Comment: Actually I am writing a VB Script code to generate a Kinetic Javascript code and my final output will be the same model actually. But do you have any idea how to get the model data in a series?

Answer (score 0):

In your vbscript you can query the diagramObjects on this particular diagram for their position.

You can then use their position to determine the order in which you generate your code.

Comment: see I am using like this:                                                                   dim diagramObjects as EA.Collection  
Set diagramObjects = theDiagram.DiagramObjects
dim diagramObject As EA.DiagramObject   (Here its using as new element that is created today assume it would come at first)

Comment: Never assume anything. Especially not when dealing with EA. Use a loop to enumerate the diagramobjects and sort them based on their position in the diagram (or other criteria that you want to use)

Comment: ya I am using a loop actually. could you please give me an example how to sort them based on their position.

Comment: There should be plenty examples of how to sort a collection on this very site. DiagramObject has attributes Top, Left, Bottom and Right which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a 'SORT_CODE' tagged value into the model and then use those in your script to sort your objects.